# Matlab: CVODE interface that takes normal Matlab ODE arguments

Tags: matlab, ode

CVODE is one of two ODE solvers that are part of the popular [SUNDIALS package](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/main.html). There is a Matlab interface provided, but the usage is not the same as the standard Matlab `ode*` interface. One has to init the solver, then step through each time point desired, and finally free the memory. Clearly, it's not a drop-in replacement for something like `ode15s`. **Has anyone written a wrapper around CVODE that takes the usual arguments for Matlab ODE solvers?**

Answer (score -1):

Well, maybe you already found the answer, but if not, you should have a look at this page:

http://bmi.bmt.tue.nl/sysbio/software/pua.html

I've been using this software for some months, and it does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I tried this software. Unfortunately, it does not take the usual Matlab ODE solver arguments--namely, it does not accept a Matlab function handle (e.g. @my_ode) as an argument, but instead, parses files written a special format and builds them into a MEX file. This format disallows any vectors or matrices. Furthermore, it only works on ODEs with a single output variable.